# Unable to debug using gdb with python inside a virtual environment (venv) on windows

Tags: python, debugging, gdb, mingw, cython

I am currently trying to debug a numpy code that I wrote using Gdb. To do that I activate first my virtual environment(on the command prompt) using the following commands (numpy_dev_env is my virtual environment)

```
numpy_dev_env\Scripts\activate
```

After that I activate my virtual environment.

```
gdb
```

then type "python" to start coding in python (all these steps work good for me).However, I realized that my test were not ran on the virtual environment,but instead on python system available in MINGW. I would appreciate your advice on ways to run the virtual enviroment with gdb.

Thank you,

I tried to configure the .gdbinit file in my home directory.I however did not know how to do with that

edit. clarified that when I run python on gdb the system used is the one available on MINGW and not of my system

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are running the correct version of Python: start python in one shell, search for the process id using your task manager, then start gdb and [attach the process](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.4/gnat_ugn_unw/Attaching-to-a-Running-Process.html).

Alternatively, start gdb with the full path to your python inside your environment.

Comment: Could you expand your comment on adding the full path inside the environment?

Comment: Start gdb as `gdb numpy_dev_env\Scripts\bin\Python`. Did you try attaching the process?

Comment: That didn't work for me. I don't have any bin folder in the virtual environment. I didn't try the first approach.

Comment: Can you at least try the other approach?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).